# Is the series $X_j = Z_0 \cos(c j)$ stationary?

Tags: expectation, covariance, variance, time-series, stationary-processes

Let

- $Z$ be a gaussian white noise with mean $0$ and variance $1$
- $c \in \mathbb{R}$ constant

Is the time series stationary? I compute the mean and variance and they look constant, am I right? if so what is the value of the auto-covariance function, $\mathbb{C}(X_j, X_{j+l})$ ?

$$\mathbb{E}(X_j) = \mathbb{E}(Z_0 \cos(cj))
= \cos(cj) \mathbb{E}(Z_0) = 0
$$

$$
\mathbb{V}(X_j) = \cos^2(cj) \mathbb{V}(Z_0) = \cos^2(cj)$$

Comment: There are different notions of stationarity: wise sense stationarity, strict stationarity, etc. In a strictly stationary process the random variables have are identically distributed and this is not true for $\{X_j\}$ Also $\mathbb V(X_j)=(\cos (cj))^{2} \mathbb V(Z_0)=(\cos (cj))^{2}$ and not 0.

Comment: I mean weak stationarity, so when expectation, variance and auto-covariance are constant. So $Z_0$ is not to be considered as constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality 
$$
\cos(cj) \mathbb{E}(Z_0) = \cos(cj) Z_0
$$
is not correct since the right hand side is random, contrarily to the left hand side.

But the computation $\mathbb E\left[X_j\right]=\cos(cj)\mathbb E\left[X_j\right]$ is correct. Therefore, the only change for $\left(X_j\right)_{j\geqslant 1}$ to be stationary in the weak or strong sense is that $\cos(cj)=1$ for all integer $j\geqslant 0$ hence $c$ should be a multiple of $2\pi$. Conversely, if $c=2k_0\pi$ for some integer $k_0$, then $X_j=Z_0$ which is stationary.